# Asynchronous File I/O in .NET

Tags: c#

I followed the example at this link, [Async I/O)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys.aspx). The example works on my local machine. However when I deploy to my test machine - Windows Server 2003, It seems to work on 24 files and then the application stops. Procmon shows that its working on 24 files and then there is no data.

My local machine is Windows XP.

The question is why would this behave this drastically between XP and Windows 2003

Comment: When you say you followed that example, did you copy it verbatim, literally copy-and-paste?  It almost sounds to me like you aren't calling the `EndRead` method.

Comment: Aaronaught: The change I made was that I log the file count in the for loop in 'ProcessImagesInBulk' method. Also each image is 200k

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the OS difference is what causes the problem. I'd be looking at other differences.

Where exactly does it stop? Can you debug it? Are the files exactly the same files as the ones on your machine?

Comment: I used the same file sample. Each file is 100K. IN the method 'ProcessImagesInBulk' in the for (int i = 0; i < numImages; i++)
loop I write out the image count and on my test machine I only geta  counter upto 24 and then there is nothing. No exception thrown either.

Comment: You need to determine more precisely where it's stopping. Either debug it or start writing logs.

Comment: That is what I am in the process of doing. Logging each step. Will post those results tomorrow.